# Swift: How to save picture in documentsDirectory with CameraManager

Tags: swift, image, frameworks, nsdocumentdirectory

I use the Camera Manager framework for my app: https://github.com/imaginary-cloud/CameraManager

I understand that to shoot image, it is pretty simple:

```
    cameraManager.capturePictureWithCompletition({ (image, error) -> Void in
    self.myImage = image             
})
```

But, I would like to stock in the documentsDirectory and not in the camera roll.

Somebody have an idea? Maybe like the Video records?

```
cameraManager.startRecordingVideo()
cameraManager.stopRecordingVideo({ (videoURL, error) -> Void in
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(videoURL, toURL: self.myVideoURL, error: &error)
})
```

Comment: relevant .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43825530/294884

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if you don't want to save in the camera roll, you have to put:

```
cameraManager.writeFilesToPhoneLibrary = false
```

And capturedImage is UIImage then:

```
 validVC.image = capturedImage
 let pictureImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(capturedImage, 0.0)
```

In case somebody else is interested.