# how to load image from local path ios swift (by path)

Tags: ios, swift, image, nsdocumentdirectory

In my app I am storing an image in local storage and I am saving the path of that image in my database. How can I load the image from that path?

Here is the code I am using in order to save the image:

```
let myimage : UIImage = UIImage(data: data)!
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
let documentDirectory = urls[0] as NSURL

print(documentDirectory)
let currentDate = NSDate()
                
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .NoStyle
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let convertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)
let imageURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(convertedDate)
imageUrlPath  = imageURL.absoluteString
print(imageUrlPath)

UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myimage,1.0)!.writeToFile(imageUrlPath, atomically: true)
```

And this is the path where my image stored

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B2A1EE50-D800-4BB0-B475-6C7F210C913C/Documents/2016-06-01%2021:49:32
```

This is how i tried to retrieve the image but it's not displaying anything.

```
let image : String = person?.valueForKey("image_local_path") as! String
print(person!.valueForKey("image_local_path")! as! String)
cell.img_message_music.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: image)
```

Comment: This line: `imageUrlPath  = imageURL.absoluteString` needs to be `imageUrlPath  = imageURL.path`

Comment: By the way, you should not take `data`, convert it to a `UIImage`, and then convert it back to a `NSData` with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. Just save the original `data`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIImage(contentsOfFile:) returning nil despite file existing in caches directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642217/uiimagecontentsoffile-returning-nil-despite-file-existing-in-caches-directory)

Comment: I was in the same scenario, be aware that your B2A1EE50xx folder changes every time you run/build/update your application like @zsyesenko said below. So you need to write to `imageUrl` not to `imageUrlPath` and save the name of your file (`convertedDate`on your case) not is path

Answer (score 62):

Folder /B2A1EE50- ... changes every time you run application.

```
../Application/B2A1EE50-D800-4BB0-B475-6C7F210C913C/Documents/..
```

Which works for me is to store fileName and get documents folder.

**Swift 5**

Create getter for directory folder

```
var documentsUrl: URL {
    return FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
}
```

Save image :

```
private func save(image: UIImage) -> String? {
    let fileName = "FileName"
    let fileURL = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
       try? imageData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
       return fileName // ----> Save fileName
    }
    print("Error saving image")
    return nil
}
```

Load image :

```
private func load(fileName: String) -> UIImage? {
    let fileURL = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    do {
        let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        return UIImage(data: imageData)
    } catch {
        print("Error loading image : \(error)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Also you can try this.

1. **Check if your path exist**

`if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(imageUrlPath) {}`

2. **Create an URL to your path**

`let url = NSURL(string: imageUrlPath)`

3. **Create data to you URL**

`let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)`

4. **Bind the url to your imageView**

`imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)`

*Final code*:

```
if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(imageUrlPath) {
    let url = NSURL(string: imageUrlPath)
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This code works for me

```
func getImageFromDir(_ imageName: String) -> UIImage? {

    if let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let fileURL = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(imageName)
        do {
            let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
            return UIImage(data: imageData)
        } catch {
            print("Not able to load image")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4:

```
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: imageUrlPath) {
            let url = NSURL(string: imageUrlPath)
            let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)

            chapterImage.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `absoluteString` with `path`

```
let myimage : UIImage = UIImage(data: data)!
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        let documentDirectory = urls[0] as NSURL


        print(documentDirectory)
        let currentDate = NSDate()

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .NoStyle
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let convertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)
        let imageURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(convertedDate)
        imageUrlPath  = imageURL.path
        print(imageUrlPath)
        UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myimage,1.0)!.writeToFile(imageUrlPath, atomically: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

This sample code may save someone some typing,

write an UIImage to disk in your own directory:

```
IM = UIImage, your image. for example, IM = someUIView.image or from the camera

let newPhotoFileName = randomNameString() + ".jpeg"
let imagePath = checkedImageDirectoryStringPath() + "/" + newPhotoFileName

let imData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(IM, 0.20)
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: imagePath, contents: imData, attributes: nil)

print("saved at filename \(newPhotoFileName)")
```

later to read that image ...

.. and convert it back to a UIImage as in a UIImageView

```
NAME = that filename, like jahgfdfs.jpg

let p = checkedImageDirectoryStringPath() + "/" + NAME
devCheckExists(fullPath: p)

var imageData: Data? = nil
do {
    let u = URL(fileURLWithPath: p)
    imageData = try Data(contentsOf: u)
}
catch {
    print("catastrophe loading file?? \(error)")
    return
}

// and then to "make that an image again"...

imageData != nil {

    picture.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    print("that seemed to work")
}
else {

    print("the imageData is nil?")
}

// or for example...

Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(imageData!,
           withName: "file", fileName: "", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    ...
```

Here are the extremely handy functions used above...

```
func checkedImageDirectoryStringPath()->String {

    // create/check OUR OWN IMAGE DIRECTORY for use of this app.

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                      .documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)

    if paths.count < 1 {
        print("some sort of disaster finding the our Image Directory - giving up")
        return "x"
        // any return will lead to disaster, so just do that
        // (it will then gracefully fail when you "try" to write etc)
    }

    let docDirPath: String = paths.first!
    let ourDirectoryPath = docDirPath.appending("/YourCompanyName")
    // so simply makes a directory called "YourCompanyName"
    // which will be there for all time, for your use

    var ocb: ObjCBool = true
    let exists = FileManager.default.fileExists(
                  atPath: ourDirectoryPath, isDirectory: &ocb)

    if !exists {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(
                    atPath: ourDirectoryPath,
                    withIntermediateDirectories: false,
                    attributes: nil)

            print("we did create our Image Directory, for the first time.")
            // never need to again
            return ourDirectoryPath
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            print("disaster trying to make our Image Directory?")
            return "x"
            // any return will lead to disaster, so just do that
        }
    }

    else {

        // already exists, as usual.
        return ourDirectoryPath
    }
}
```

and

```
func randomNameString(length: Int = 7)->String{

    enum s {
        static let c = Array("abcdefghjklmnpqrstuvwxyz12345789".characters)
        static let k = UInt32(c.count)
    }

    var result = [Character](repeating: "a", count: length)

    for i in 0..<length {
        let r = Int(arc4random_uniform(s.k))
        result[i] = s.c[r]
    }

    return String(result)
}
```

and

```
func devCheckExists(fullPath: String) {

    var ocb: ObjCBool = false
    let itExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fullPath, isDirectory: &ocb)
    if !itExists {
        // alert developer. processes will fail at next step
        print("\n\nDOES NOT EXIST\n\(fullPath)\n\n")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me and I think is a fast and clean way to do it.

**Swift 5.0**

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
let documentDirectory = urls[0] as NSURL

print(documentDirectory)
let currentDate = NSDate()

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .NoStyle
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let convertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)
let imageURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(convertedDate)
let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl)
let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
```

Where "imageUrl" is the value of your imageURL from documents folder. And "image" is the resulting image you can use anywhere you need.

Answer (score -4):

1.cell.image.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)

2.cell.image.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)

3.cell.image.image =  UIImage(contentsOfFile: urlString!)

Comment: Don't name "image" something that is not an image. You end up with ridiculous naming such as "image.image" here in your example.

Comment: Your are off topic dude :-/