# Swift 3.0 and iOS: How to set the delete privileges of a file in Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, privileges, file-management

If I attempt to remove a file using the **FileManager** class I get an error.

The function below returns **true**, which means that I need to set the **delete privileges** attributes. However I [haven't](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/ManagingFIlesandDirectories/ManagingFIlesandDirectories.html) found an example on how to do it.

```
func isDeletableFile(atPath path: String) -> Bool
```

Any help?

**Code:**

```
func fileManager(_ fileManager: FileManager, shouldRemoveItemAtPath path: String) -> Bool {
   // print("Should remove invoked for path \(path)")
    return true
}

func fileManager(_ fileManager: FileManager, shouldProceedAfterError error: Error, removingItemAt URL: URL) -> Bool {
    //print("Should process")
    return true
}

func deleteAllFiles(subPath : String) {
    var url = Bundle.main.bundleURL
    url = url.appendingPathComponent(subPath)

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    fileManager.delegate = self

    if let enumerator = fileManager.enumerator(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil) {
        for file in enumerator {
            let fileAsNSURL = file as! NSURL
            print("")
            print("Deleting: \(fileAsNSURL.absoluteString!)")
            print("")

            do {
                // I would like to set the deletable permissions before checking this..
                if (fileManager.isDeletableFile(atPath: fileAsNSURL.absoluteString!)){
                    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: fileAsNSURL.absoluteString!)
                }
                else{
                    print("its not deletable")
                }
            }
            catch let error {
                print("file-delete-error:\n\(error) for path \(fileAsNSURL.absoluteString!)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642217/uiimagecontentsoffile-returning-nil-despite-file-existing-in-caches-directory/40643037?s=1|0.8206#40643037

Comment: Thanks! It did help solving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a common misunderstanding:

In the file system a you have to call **`path`** on the URL to get the path

```
fileManager.isDeletableFile(atPath: fileAsNSURL.path)
```

`absoluteString` returns the (percent escaped) string representation of the URL starting with the scheme (`http://`, `file://`)

---

For example you have an URL (don't use `NSURL` in Swift 3):

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/Users/myUser/Application Support")
```

- `url.path` returns `"/Users/myUser/Application Support"`
- `url.absoluteString` returns `"file:///Users/myUser/Application%20Support"`