# Range issue in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I got an error message when I call the following method

```
pathString.removeSubrange(Range(pathString.startIndex..<pathString.index(pathString.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)))
```

Here is the error message

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<_>' with an argument list of
>   type '(Range)'

How would I change these statements to get rid of this error the transfer over to `XCode 10` and `Swift 4.2` is really giving me a hard time.

Looks like this

```
if pathString.contains("file://") {
    let startIndex = pathString.startIndex
    let endIndex = pathString.index(pathString.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
    let range = startIndex..<endIndex
    pathString.removeSubrange(range)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the edit but does anyone have any idea

Comment: Please don't hack your file url path. Learn the differences from absoluteString and path properties of a URL

Comment: @LeoDabus can you post an example of how i should use it

Comment: Show your actual problem. You shouldn't be working with strings (path) anymore. You should use only URL. if you have no alternative just check if the file:// prefix is present use `URL(string:)` initializer if the scheme it is not present use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` initializer.

Comment: This might help also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40643037/2303865 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34135437/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call the `Range` initializer. Just do the following

```
pathString.removeSubrange(pathString.startIndex..<pathString.index(pathString.startIndex, offsetBy: 7))
```

or this, for more readability

```
let startIndex = pathString.startIndex
let endIndex = pathString.index(pathString.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
let range = startIndex..<endIndex
pathString.removeSubrange(range)
```

**UPDATE**

In comments, Leo Dabus suggested the better solution

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    mutating func removePrefix(_ prefix: String) {
        if hasPrefix(prefix) {
            removeFirst(prefix.count)
        }
    }
}
```

After adding that you can simply call

```
pathString.removePrefix("file://")
```

Comment: umm i still get the same error even when i changed it

Comment: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<_>' with an argument list of type '(Range<String.Index>)'

Comment: Are you sure that you've changed it in all cases? Because now you `range` has an appropriate type and the error should not occur.

Comment: @HiDungLing Yep. This error occurs for code from your question because you're calling `Range()` and get the range of the wrong type. For code from my answer, this error should not appear.

Comment: @HiDungLing That's weird. The updated code gives you the same error? Have you tried to rebuild your project?

Comment: yup and yes it does

Comment: @HiDungLing Just to make sure, does `pathString` has a `String` type?

Comment: let me check bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180480/discussion-between-yury-imashev-and-hidungling).

Comment: This is a terrible approach. OP shouldn't be striping off the url scheme out of the string. Btw why not simply `str.dropFirst(7)` ???

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank a lot for your comment! I update my answer with a better approach.

Comment: @YuryImashev better too extend StringProtocol and constrain it to RangeReplacebleCollection, then you can use mutating method removeFirst(n: Int). Note that extending StringProtocol instead of String you make the method available also for substrings

Comment: Your extension method should look like this `extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    mutating func removePrefix(_ prefix: String) {
        if hasPrefix(prefix) { removeFirst(prefix.count) }
    }
}`

Comment: But again OP shouldn't be striping off the url scheme from the absoluteString.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the suggestion! Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there this looks like it's solved by this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719696/7932935

In your case replace:

```
pathString.removeSubrange(Range(pathString.startIndex..<pathString.index(pathString.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)))
```

with:

```
pathString.removeSubrange(pathString.startIndex..<pathString.index(pathString.startIndex, offsetBy: 7))
```

Comment: I tested it on a Playground and it works for swift 4.2, like Yuri below is pathString a string? cheers!