# Loading Data object from local file in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, io

I'm struggling to get an image file loaded in Swift 3.
Here is the code:

```
do {
    let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: imageUrl2.asURL()) 
} catch { 
    print ("loading image file error") 
}
```

And `imageUrl2` is:

```
file:///Users/veikoherne/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/889A08D5-B8CC-458C-99FF-643A4BA1A806/data/Containers/Data/Application/F64ED326-7894-4EE7-AA3B-B1BB10DF8259/Documents/img2017-03-23 17:39:24.jpg
```

and obviously I have checked that this file exists and is valid image. It always ends up telling me *"loading image file error"*. Anyone have experiences loading local data in Swift 3?

The answer mentioned was using `NSData` object and probably Swift 2. Current Swift 3 refuses to bridge `NSData` to `Data`, that's why I have to use `Data`.

Comment: Where does `imageUrl2` come from? And what does `asURL()`? And you might print the actual caught **error** rather than a generic string.

Comment: @vadian expresses some good questions. One more: *...experiences loading local data...* - local to what? Your project, a Framework, the OS file system...??? I'll add one more option looking at your URL - is this in the Photos library? Trust me, there are several places, each with a "best" way to get at them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to load image from local path ios swift (by path)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37574689/how-to-load-image-from-local-path-ios-swift-by-path)

Comment: The answer is using NSData which was OK in Swift 2. Swift 3 demands me to use Data instead of NSData..

Comment: to @vadian imageUrl is the string for the file and as Data object needs URL, I have to convert String to Url by using .asURL(). It's not a photo library, it's a image I store in app documents directory. Obviously I'm using the latest xCode to have Swift 3.

Comment: I know what it's supposed to be, but the the way to get the string could be wrong and the way to create the URL could also be wrong. Once again, print the  error in the catch clause. The question is too broad.

Comment: to @vadian: The error could be empty, but I have seen "Invalid Url" as well. That's why I posted my Url String.

Comment: This is at least a hint. Then most likely the `asURL()` function creates an invalid URL – as suspected in very my first comment. Check that.

Answer (score 33):

Loading data from local file you should use `contentsOfFile:` method.

So in case of reading *data* you can use:

```
Data(contentsOf: <URL>, options: <Data.ReadingOptions>)
```

Reading a plain *text* as a `String`, use:

```
String(contentsOfFile: <LocalFileDirPath>)
```

Reading an *image* from document directory, use:

```
UIImage(contentsOfFile: <LocalFileDirPath>)
```

Hope this would be helpful! ([Further sample code](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-load-a-string-from-a-file-in-your-bundle).)

Comment: Using contentsOfFile will give me compile error: "Argument labels '(contentsOfFile:)' do not match any available overloads"

Comment: Use this method:

Data(contentsOf: <URL>, options: <Data.ReadingOptions>)

Comment: Tried options: Data.ReadingOptions.uncachedRead or Data.ReadingOptions.mappedRead without any luck. Still same.

Comment: I have updated my answer for reading an image from document directory. I am using this in my current project. Hope this would be helpful now.

Comment: Thanks Dharmesh. I'm reading data in a way you describe, but can't get it work. Can you confirm, that it works for you? What options do you use? Can you give me your sample URL?

Comment: I am using "UIImage(contentsOfFile: <LocalFileDirPath>)" for reading image from my app's document directory which was downloaded earlier and saved in dir. And this works for me.

Answer (score 18):

I experienced the same issue when trying to retrieve a file that I just downloaded. If you have saved a file from some url like I did, this should work:

```
let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
let localUrl = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("somefile.txt")

if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: localUrl.path){
    if let cert = NSData(contentsOfFile: localUrl.path) {
        return cert as Data
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works thanks to the ```.path``` on URL :)

Answer (score 11):

Swift 5 version.

```
func loadFileFromLocalPath(_ localFilePath: String) ->Data? {
   return try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: localFilePath))
}
```