# Displaying image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimage

There are many examples on how to use imageWithContentsOfFile in object-c, but how do I use it in Swift. `imageView.image = UIImage(imageWithContentsOfFile: imageName)`
returns Argument labels '(imageWithContentsOfFile:)' do not match any available overloads

while if I write: `imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile:imageName)`
It doesn't display the image.

(I have all images stores in Media.xcassets)
I am displaying a lot of images so using UIImage(named:imageName) isn't a viable option. How can I get the functionality of contentsOfFile in swift?

Comment: Which swift version are you uing ?

Comment: `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)` is correct in Swift 4. But it takes the file URL, not the file's name... Anyway: please read Apple's documentation.

Comment: see this once it helpes you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37574689/how-to-load-image-from-local-path-ios-swift-by-path

Answer (score -1):

Swift code:

```
func getImage (named name : String) -> UIImage?
{
    if let imgPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: ".png")
    {
        return UIImage(contentsOfFile: imgPath)
    }
    return nil
}

//Image name "MyImage.png"

getImage(named: "MyImage")!
```

Comment: Please explain what is the code supposed to do and how it is supposed to help. They are specifically asking about `imageWithContentsOfFile` which you don't mention at all. Best regards